# Функция для вывода окна подтверждения

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая встроенная функция JavaScript выводит всплывающее окно в браузере, похожее на окно, которое выводится функцией alert, только с кнопками "OK" и "Отмена"? И можно ли управлять текстом, которое выводит это функция?

Comment: [confirm](http://javascript.ru/confirm)

Comment: Великий вопрос.

Comment: @Kremchik, зато, как народ оживился! Все ринулись делиться своими несметными познаниями ))

Comment: предлагаю для определения верного ответа использовать считалочку

Comment: @Deonis солидарен)

Comment: А теперь вопрос посложнее - функция confirm выводит окошко с кнопками ОК и Cancel, а если я хочу чтобы были кнопки ОК и Отмена, мне нужно писать свою функцию с нуля?

Comment: в опере "ОК и Отмена", но вообще да, писать свою

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var a = confirm("Хотите нажать OK?");
```

Answer (score 6):

confirm("Уверены?")

возвращает true/false в зависимости от нажатой кнопки.

Answer (score 4):

`confirm()`:

```
if (confirm('Вы хотите ...?'))
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

функция confirm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: >if (r==true)

удивительно

Comment: @Spectre, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp))

Comment: Сам иногда про это забываю...))

Comment: пфф...чего мелочиться

    if(r == true & r != false)

>& это побитовый оператор а && логический

КО залогиньтесь

Comment: будто я сам его писал...)) это из поисковика))

Comment: @Spectre & это побитовый оператор а && логический

Comment: @Rules, корректировать чужой ответ, не предложив для начала это сделать автору такового - поменьшей мере безтактно. ИМХО.

Comment: ok не буду :) Просто руки чешутся чтото подредактировать...

Comment: @Spectre 

>КО залогиньтесь

что???? I don't understend you :)